Integration over measure which counts jump discontinuities of specific length.
$f:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ is a monotonically increasing function with $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$. Let $p>1$.
Define, for $0\leq a < b \leq 1$, $\mu((a,b])$ as the number of points $x \in [0,1]$ such that
$\lim_{h\to 0+} [f(x+h) - f(x)] \in (a,b]$, i.e. the length of the jump at $x$ is between $a$ and $b$.
I want to prove that $\int_0^1 t^p d\mu < \infty$. By observing that $\mu((a,b])  \leq [\frac{1}{a}]$, I could prove that $\int_0^1 t^{p-1} \mu([t,1]) dt < \infty$.
I am unable to proceed. Please help.

Are you sure $\mu <<Leb$?

Oh right. The radon nikodym derivative might not exist. I will edit the question right away.

Maybe the layer cake representation will help here? $\int_0^1 x^p d\mu(x) = \int_0^\infty \mu( {x\in[0,1]:x^p>t}) dt \leq \int_0^1 \mu([t^{1/p},\infty))dt \leq \int_0^1 t^{1/p}dt$
